# Change Header according to filter applied

Tags: tableau-api

In Tableau 10.5.2 I have two fields SizeSQM and SQFT.
I have a Filter: Unit of measure which list 2 options.

1) '000 sqft
2) '000 sqm

When I select' 000 sqft, I would like the header of the dataset to change to the field SizeSQFT and display the SQFT header.

When I select' 000 sqm, I would like the header of the dataset to change to the field SizeSQM and display the SQM header.

I don't want to create separate sheets.

Thank you

Comment: Learn about parameters

Answer (score 0):

I created a calculated field which referred to the parameter options selected by the user. it worked.